# .Net - Problems converting code-snippet from C# to VB.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have problems in converting the following code-snippet from C# to VB.Net:

```
if ((currentItem.Tag as FileSystemKind?) != FileSystemKind.File)
            {
                if (currentFileName == GOBACK)
                    currentPath = currentPath.Substring(0, currentPath.Length - Path.GetFileName(currentPath).Length - 1);
                else
                    currentPath = Path.Combine(currentPath, currentFileName);
                UpdateControls();
            }
            else
            {
                //If it's a file, we should return the selected filename
                fileName = Path.Combine(currentPath, currentFileName);
                EndOk();
            }
```

The problem lies in the following line:

```
if ((currentItem.Tag as FileSystemKind?) != FileSystemKind.File)
```

I have tried two different online-converters which suggested me the following conversions (for above line):

1st one:

```
If (TryCast(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind)?) <> FileSystemKind.File Then
```

2nd one:

```
If TryCast(currentItem.Tag, System.Nullable(Of FileSystemKind)) <> FileSystemKind.File Then
```

The error I get in VB.Net is:

> TryCast' operand must be reference type, but 'FileSystemKind?' is a value type.

The code is from a project targeting the Net.Compact Framework 2.0 but I think most should be compatible with the ordinary Compact Framework.

I am lost. Anyone who can help me out?

PS: I am sorry for the layout of the code in the question. Is there a way to change the font size to a smaller one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If currentItem.Tag is always of type FileSystemKind you could try

```
If (DirectCast(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind) <> FileSystemKind.File) Then
```

if currentItem.Tag is *not* always of type FileSystemKind you could try

```
        If TypeOf (currentItem.Tag) Is FileSystemKind Then
            If (DirectCast(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind) <> FileSystemKind.File) Then
            End If
        Else
            ' handle different types
        End If
```

You may also use "CType" to convert or cast the type of the variant object "currentItem.Tag" to type FileSystemKind

```
If (CType(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind) <> FileSystemKind.File) Then
```

Comment: roygbiv: the statement you suggested 
"If (CType(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind) <> FileSystemKind.File) Then" resolved everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Load up your compiled .dll in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), then change the view language to VB and it translates it for you.

```
 If (DirectCast(TryCast(currentItem.Tag,FileSystemKind?), FileSystemKind) <> FileSystemKind.File) Then
    End If
```

Comment: Yeap- that would of been my suggestion but you beat to it.

Comment: Hej Mikael: yes, that's another converter I didn't think about. I'll keep that in mind next time I encounter similar issues.

Comment: It works for other .Net languages as well. And the output from it is shorter than the suggested solution further up. Vote me up :)

Answer (score 1):

```
If TypeOf(currentItem.Tag) Is FileSystemKind AndAlso CType(currentItem.Tag, FileSystemKind) = FileSystemKind.File Then
```

Comment: He's not testing if it is an enum type, he's testing whether it is an enum value.